# Hibernate not populating elementCollection even if query is valid

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, sql-server-2017

I have a `User` table with usernames. These usernames can be written in upper and lower case. I also have a second table to manage `user permissions`.

Assume this data:

User table:

```
userName    userPassword
--------------------------
test        test
john        password
DOE         testtest
```

User permission table:

```
userId    permissionId
-------------------------
test      permission1
JOHN      PERMISSION1
DOE       permission2
```

The user permissions are actually an enum and are mapped like following in the `User` class:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = UserPermission.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_PERMISSION", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"))
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "permissionId")
@ColumnTransformer(read = "UPPER(permissionId)")
private List<UserPermission> userPermissionList;
```

I use this mapping to make sure that the permissions that are read, are always upper case to make sure that they can be converted to the actual enum value.

Now I get a problem on joining the `user` table with the `user permission` table with hibernate. In hibernate the `userName` and `userId` column need to have the exact same value (including the case), otherwise the user has no permissions. This means that

```
test == test
john != JOHN
DOE  == DOE
```

If user `john` tries to login, he has no permissions, because hibernate can't match the username to the `user permission` table. I thought that an easy workaround would be, to have hibernate treat both columns (`userName` and `userId`) as upper case columns (at least for the join) but I couldn't find any information on this topic.

**How can I tell hibernate to treat the columns on which a join happens as `UPPER()` columns?**

---

The database used in question is MSSQL 2017 which is case-insensitive as proven by the results of this query:

```
select * from User inner join USER_PERMISSION on userName = userId
```

which results in

```
userName    userPassword    userId    permissionId
------------------------------------------------------
test        test            test      permission1
john        password        JOHN      PERMISSION1
DOE         testtest        DOE       permission2
```

---

EDIT:

As requested, the actual query generated by hibernate:

```
select
    userpermis0_.userId as userId1_8_0_,
    UPPER(userpermis0_.permissionId) as permissi2_8_0_ 
from
    dbo.USER_PERMISSION userpermis0_ 
where
    userpermis0_.userId=?
```

No matter how I look at it, there should be no reason at all to not fetch results for this query

EDIT 2:

This is my sessionfactory configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    scope="singleton">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>mainFirst.MATRICS</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> -->

            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

            <!-- optimize -->
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">16</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</prop>

            <!-- charset -->
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And the full classes and mappings:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Id
    private String userName;
    private String encryptedPassword;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Calendar lastLoginDateTime;
    private Calendar nextPasswordChangeDate;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String emailSignature;
    private Boolean allowedToLoginFlag;
    private Boolean passwordChangeRequiredFlag;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = UserPermission.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "USER_PERMISSION", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "permissionId")
    @ColumnTransformer(read = "UPPER(permissionId)")
    private List<UserPermission> userPermissionList;

    public User() {

    }
    //ommit getter and setter and other methods
}
```

UserPermission enum:

```
public enum UserPermission {

    PERMISSION1("PERMISSION1"), PERMISSION2("PERMISSION2");

    private String identifier;

    UserPermission(String name) {

        this.identifier = name;
    }

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you check the generated query?

Comment: @Rohit I checked the queries generated. Instead of an actual join, hibernate executes two separate queries. the first fetches the user (works fine) and the second fetches the user permissions for the user. I couldn't get the actual parameters as of now, but I will include the second query in the question. And unless hibernate uses the wrong value (which I also doubt), there is no reason that query should not return anything

Comment: I now also got the used value. It is the `userName` value as its read from the `User` table. I already tried to have it read the value as uppercase with using another `@ColumnTransformer(read = "UPPER(userName)")`, but that column transformer only acts on the `WHERE` clause for some reason

Comment: I found the reason that the `@ColumnTransformer` is not applied to my `User`. Its because of [HHH-9808](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9808). This still does not solve the problem at hand where hibernate is unable to load the `@ElementCollection` even if the query is completely valid in SQL and even yields the right results if executed like hibernate would do

Comment: It is strange that Hibernate does not generate a join query despite having `FetchType.EAGER`. I do not have experience with MSSQL, but in case of your actual query generated on `USER_PERMISSION`, oracle and mysql would not return results as well.

Comment: MSSQL is case-insensitive. I checked with the exact same query via Aqua Data Studio as well as SQL Server Management Studio and both applications returned me the expected results. The only reason it might not perform the join could be the `@ElementCollection` as well as the `@ColumnTransformer`. Though I am really not sure what the actual reason is

Comment: I quickly checked `@ElementCollection` with both `@Collectiontable` and `@JoinTable` along with `@ColumnTransformer` in my project. In both cases Hibernate generated join query as long as I had `FetchType.EAGER` as I suspected. I used H2 db.

Comment: About case sensitivity, may be the JPA MSSQL dailect has some setting to influence it?

Comment: I couldn't find any settings to influence it. Currently it should fetch some results but discard them as the identifier doesn't match case-sensitive. I have now included the classes with the their mappings as well as the hibernate settings, in case those are interesting at all. How exactly did you fetch the result? Because I run an HQL as the actual PK is on `id` and not on `userName` in the database (I would prefer not to change the database)

Comment: It gets stranger and stranger. Depending on the case of the username, hibernate now executes two separate queries for lower case and just one query for upper case. I really don't get what happens here

Comment: As I have no idea for any other workaround, I will simply only call the method with upper case userName. I will also ensure that the `user permissions` table only contains upper case userNames to make sure that it works consistently